# Combining dataframes with different number of columns and rows

Tags: r

I have two data frames with different numbers of columns and rows. I want to combine them into one data frame.

```
df.A

 Company Investor_A Investor_B Investor_C 
   St      0.07        0.06      0.06
   ab      NA          0.08      NA
   ta      0.9         NA        NA

df.B

  Weight_A Weight_B Weight_C
    0.3       0.5     0.2
```

The output that I want is like this:

```
  Company Investor_A Investor_B Investor_C Weight_A Weight_B Weight_C
   St      0.07        0.06      0.06         0.3     0.5      0.2
   ab      NA          0.08      NA           0.3     0.5      0.2
   ta      0.9         NA        NA           0.3     0.5      0.2
```

I tried cbind but it gives me an error, cbind (df.A, df.B)

The important thing is

1 - Keep the column order of the combined the data.frames.
2 - df.B only has values in the 1st row. I would like the values for each column to fill the rows in the combined column.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could replicate the second data `cbind(df.A, df.B[rep(1, nrow(df.A)),])`. It may be better to provide the structure of data as I couldn't find any error with your code as well

Comment: `cbind(df.A, df.B)` works fine for me. What was your error? Reproducible example showing this logic is valid in R - `cbind(data.frame(a=1:2,b=2:3), data.frame(weight_a=1, weight_b=2))`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CISCO - can you report what was the issue? It could be helpful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
cbind(df.A, df.B[rep(1,3),])
```

Answer (score -1):

`dplyr::bind_cols()` works in this case.

**EDIT**: but `cbind` should work on the example data too, as noted in the comments.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df.A, df.B)
```